# Why doesn't multi-constraint work in this case?

Tags: c++, physics, physics-engine, rigid-body-dynamics

The situation is as follows:

There are two objects and there are 3 constraints between the two objects.

> $$
> \dot{C}=(\vec{V}_{rel_a} - \vec{V}_{rel_b}) \cdot normalize(\vec{p_{a}} - \vec{p_{b}})
> $$
> "Pa" and "Pb" is constraint point on object, "V_rel" is relative velocity of constraint point

I used the formula in the picture below to calculate and the calculated result was incorrect. Why is this?

The result is that the constraint equation is not satisfied, and the relative velocities of the three constraint points are not equal.

[image: constraint formula]

---

this is test data:

```
    float fMass1 = 100;
    float fMass2 = 100;
    const VECTOR3<float> vCenter[] = { VECTOR3<float>(0, 9, 0), VECTOR3<float>(0, 0, 0) };
    const VECTOR3<float> ContactPoint[] = { VECTOR3<float>(-3, 4.5, -3), VECTOR3<float>(-3, 4.5, 3), VECTOR3<float>(3, 4.5, -3), VECTOR3<float>(3, 4.5, 3) };
    const VECTOR3<float> vSize = VECTOR3<float>(6, 9, 6);

    VECTOR3<float> vVelocity1           = VECTOR3<float>(0, 20, 0);
    VECTOR3<float> vAngularVelocity1    = VECTOR3<float>(0, 0, -3);

    VECTOR3<float> vVelocity2           = VECTOR3<float>(0, 80, 0);
    VECTOR3<float> vAngularVelocity2    = VECTOR3<float>(10, 0, 0);
```

this is core code:

```
template<typename T>
void VelocityMultipleConstraint(const VelocityConstraintParameter<T>* param)
{
    MATRIX<3, 12, double> Jacobian;
    MATRIX<12, 12, double> InverseMass;
    MATRIX<12, 1, double> Velocity;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Jacobian(i, 0) = param[i].vDirection.x;
        Jacobian(i, 1) = param[i].vDirection.y;
        Jacobian(i, 2) = param[i].vDirection.z;

        const VECTOR3<T> vRadiusObject1 = param[i].vObj1ContactPoint - param[i].vBarycenter1;
        const VECTOR3<T> vRadiusCrossNormal1 = cross(vRadiusObject1, param[i].vDirection);

        Jacobian(i, 3) = vRadiusCrossNormal1.x;
        Jacobian(i, 4) = vRadiusCrossNormal1.y;
        Jacobian(i, 5) = vRadiusCrossNormal1.z;

        Jacobian(i, 6) = -param[i].vDirection.x;
        Jacobian(i, 7) = -param[i].vDirection.y;
        Jacobian(i, 8) = -param[i].vDirection.z;

        const VECTOR3<T> vRadiusObject2 = param[i].vObj2ContactPoint - param[i].vBarycenter2;
        const VECTOR3<T> vRadiusCrossNormal2 = cross(-vRadiusObject2, param[i].vDirection);

        Jacobian(i, 9) = vRadiusCrossNormal2.x;
        Jacobian(i, 10) = vRadiusCrossNormal2.y;
        Jacobian(i, 11) = vRadiusCrossNormal2.z;
    }
    InverseMass(0, 0) = param[0].fInverseMass1;             InverseMass(1, 1) = param[0].fInverseMass1;                 InverseMass(2, 2) = param[0].fInverseMass1;
    InverseMass(3, 3) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(0, 0);   InverseMass(3, 4) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(0, 1);       InverseMass(3, 5) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(0, 2);
    InverseMass(4, 3) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(1, 0);   InverseMass(4, 4) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(1, 1);       InverseMass(4, 5) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(1, 2);
    InverseMass(5, 3) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(2, 0);   InverseMass(5, 4) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(2, 1);       InverseMass(5, 5) = param[0].mtInverseInertia1(2, 2);


    InverseMass(6, 6) = param[0].fInverseMass2;               InverseMass(7, 7) = param[0].fInverseMass2;               InverseMass(8, 8) = param[0].fInverseMass2;
    InverseMass(9, 9) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(0, 0);     InverseMass(9, 10) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(0, 1);     InverseMass(9, 11) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(0, 2);
    InverseMass(10, 9) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(1, 0);     InverseMass(10, 10) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(1, 1);     InverseMass(10, 11) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(1, 2);
    InverseMass(11, 9) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(2, 0);     InverseMass(11, 10) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(2, 1);     InverseMass(11, 11) = param[0].mtInverseInertia2(2, 2);

    Velocity(0, 0) = param[0].vVelocity1.x;         Velocity(1, 0) = param[0].vVelocity1.y;            Velocity(2, 0) = param[0].vVelocity1.z;
    Velocity(3, 0) = param[0].vAngularVelocity1.x;  Velocity(4, 0) = param[0].vAngularVelocity1.y;     Velocity(5, 0) = param[0].vAngularVelocity1.z;
    Velocity(6, 0) = param[0].vVelocity2.x;         Velocity(7, 0) = param[0].vVelocity2.y;            Velocity(8, 0) = param[0].vVelocity2.z;
    Velocity(9, 0) = param[0].vAngularVelocity2.x;  Velocity(10, 0) = param[0].vAngularVelocity2.y;     Velocity(11, 0) = param[0].vAngularVelocity2.z;

    MATRIX<3, 1, double> Lambda = inverse( Jacobian * InverseMass * Jacobian.transpose()) * (-Jacobian * Velocity);

    MATRIX<12, 1, double> DeltaV = InverseMass * Jacobian.transpose() * Lambda;

    *param[0].pOutVelocity1          = VECTOR3<float>(param[0].vVelocity1.x + DeltaV(0, 0), param[0].vVelocity1.y + DeltaV(1, 0), param[0].vVelocity1.z + DeltaV(2, 0));
    *param[0].pOutAngularVelocity1   = VECTOR3<float>(param[0].vAngularVelocity1.x + DeltaV(3, 0), param[0].vAngularVelocity1.y + DeltaV(4, 0), param[0].vAngularVelocity1.z + DeltaV(5, 0));
    *param[0].pOutVelocity2          = VECTOR3<float>(param[0].vVelocity2.x + DeltaV(6, 0), param[0].vVelocity2.y + DeltaV(7, 0), param[0].vVelocity2.z + DeltaV(8, 0));
    *param[0].pOutAngularVelocity2   = VECTOR3<float>(param[0].vAngularVelocity2.x + DeltaV(9, 0), param[0].vAngularVelocity2.y + DeltaV(10, 0), param[0].vAngularVelocity2.z + DeltaV(11, 0));
   
}
```

This is the relative velocity of the center of mass of the three constraint points:

```
constraint point : 0
before : 1 :{x=-13.5000000 y=29.0000000 z=0.00000000 ...} 2 : {x=0.00000000 y=110.000000 z=45.0000000 ...}
constraint point : 1
before : 1 :{x=-13.5000000 y=29.0000000 z=0.00000000 ...} 2 : {x=0.00000000 y=50.0000000 z=45.0000000 ...}
constraint point : 2
before : 1 :{x=-13.5000000 y=11.0000000 z=0.00000000 ...} 2 : {x=0.00000000 y=110.000000 z=45.0000000 ...}
after : 1 : {x=5.06883144 y=45.9733505 z=0.528086662 ...} , 2 : {x=-9.93715286 y=54.8153305 z=-10.8799744 ...}
after : 1 : {x=-3.84213710 y=38.4656563 z=0.528086662 ...} , 2 : {x=-1.02618432 y=61.1101532 z=-10.8799744 ...}
after : 1 : {x=5.06883144 y=42.5455589 z=9.43905544 ...} , 2 : {x=-9.93715286 y=57.8786316 z=-19.7909431 ...}
```

***According to the constraint equation, the velocities of the three constraint points should be equal.***

[This is the full source code on GitHub](https://github.com/noodlerun/multi-impluse/blob/main/test.cpp)

Comment: Please show the code you are referring to that "doesn't work". We aren't mind readers.

Comment: @Casey ok, I added the core code to this question page and I also uploaded the source code to GITHUB.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your message on Discord and responded, albeit kind of late. Apologies. Here's the copy of the response.

Given multiple contact constraint points between two rigid bodies, it is normal that they have different linear and angular velocity, unless there is an additional constraint to fix the relative rotation between the two bodies.